# Template doesn't get applied for a directive inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a directive inside a directive that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<test-directive></test-directive>

<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("testDirective", ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div>just a test</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            let autocomplete = $compile('<test-chart></test-chart>');
            let content = autocomplete(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    };
}]);

app.directive('testChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                controllerAs: 'chartCtrl',
                template: '<div><div id="container"></div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
                controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                    var hc = Highcharts.chart('container', {

                    });
                }]
            };
        })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHYNMDW67ST5

The problem I'm having is when the inner directive is trying to initialize the highchart using:

```
var hc = Highcharts.chart('container', { });
```

This issues a highchart error #13 which is when highchart can't find an element to create a chart on. In this example: `<div id="container">`

Looking at the document inside the controller for the inner directive it seems to be missing the template of the directive. Thats why highchart is getting #13.

[image]

Why is not the inner directive template getting applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your `testDirective`'s linking function:

```
let autocomplete = $compile('<test-chart></test-chart>');
// Your test chart is detached here and thus its controller can't find container in the DOM
let content = autocomplete(scope);
// This line of code is never executed because the previous one throws that's why you never see your test chart being appended to the DOM
element.append(content);
```

To fix that you first need to append your `autocomplete` to the DOM. And only then perform compilation and linking. Basically you can go like that:

```
let content = angular.element('<test-chart></test-chart>');
element.append(content);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```